# lower counter cache when archiving activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I created a module that my activerecords include that supports archiving. This allows me to call archive! and unarchive! on those objects in order to update the archive field.

I'm wondering what I could do in order to decrement the counter cache that these objects do as it's done when the destroy! command is called.

My model looks like this...

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Archivable

  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: :posts_count
  validates_presence_of :user_id
end
```

How do I decrement the posts_count column in the users model everytime a post gets archived?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do this manually - instead I'd create an `archived` scope - and add a new counter cache that covers the un-archived records only - it'll keep track of itself that way :)

But, I think you can also manually decrement a counter (at the end of your archive method) using something like:

```
User.decrement_counter(:posts_count, user.id)
```

Comment: Thanks man. Can you point me in the right direction as far as modifying my existing counter caches to cover a specific scope? ie. records that have archived marked as false. Thanks a lot